# Replace a String with specific list of strings in java

Tags: java, json, string, arraylist, replace

Here is the example,

```
public class Demo{

    public static void main (String args[]) {

        List<String> varList = Arrays.asList("VAR_TEMP", "VAR_TEMPA", "VAR_TEMPB");
        String operation = "var temp = VAR_TEMPB";

        for (String var : varList) {
            operation = (operation.contains(var))
                    ? operation.replace(var, "'HI'")
                            : operation;
        }

        System.out.println("Final operation : " + operation);
    }
}
```

I am trying to replace the Operation string with list of strings.

I am expecting the response for the above code is like,

> Final operation : var temp = HI

But it is giving the response like below,

> Final operation : var temp = 'HI'B

While iterating the list of String it is taking the first matching`("VAR_TEMP")` instead of taking the exact match`("VAR_TEMPB")`.
Can you please suggest the way to achieve this the expected response.

Comment: Move `"VAR_TEMP"` to the end of your list.

Comment: More generally: if any string to be replaced is a substring of another, it must be behind that string. Alternatively you can ensure that no string is a substring of another by including something like word boundaries.

Comment: @khelwood The list may be come in any order. For understanding I have mentioned like this.  I expecting a generic solution for this.

Comment: For an exact match, you should use `equals` instead of `contains`. So you have to split the `operation` and have to check for equality.

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran yes, i tried that too, but the operation may be in the form of lengthy code like,
`String operation = "var temp = VAR_TEMPB; var newTemp = VAR_TEMPA {}";`
So there is no common key for splitting the operation and that leads to very long logic code with if conditions.

Comment: @ArulAM Even if the list can come in any order, you can still sort it to put the longer strings first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List is declared as
`List<String> varList = Arrays.asList("VAR_TEMP", "VAR_TEMPA", "VAR_TEMPB");`

Operation is `String operation = "var temp = VAR_TEMPB";`

The loop acts as following:

1. Does operation (var temp = VAR_TEMPB) contains VAR_TEMP? Yes
2. Now operation now is **var temp = 'HI'B**
3. Does operation (var temp = 'HI'B) contains VAR_TEMPA? No. Operation is not changed
4. Does operation (var temp = 'HI'B) contains VAR_TEMPB? No. Operation is not changed

---

A simple solution should be the use of Regular Expression, when you express the exact matching pattern. For example:

```
class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final List<Pattern> varList =
        Arrays.asList(
            Pattern.compile("(VAR_TEMP)$"),
            Pattern.compile("(VAR_TEMPA)$"),
            Pattern.compile("(VAR_TEMPB)$"));

    String operation = "var temp = VAR_TEMPB";

    Matcher tmp;
    for (Pattern item : varList) {
      tmp = item.matcher(operation);
      operation = tmp.find() ? operation.replace(tmp.group(), "'HI'") : operation;
    }

    System.out.println("Final operation : " + operation);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the flow, how to overcome the issue?

Comment: You could use Regular Expression. I updated the answer with a basic example

Comment: It's working, thanks Sigur.